# Open Camera in another View in iOS

Tags: ios, delegates, uiimagepickercontroller

How can I call this method from my **MainController.m** class and pass the Image to my MainController

**CameraController.m**

```
- (void) openCamera {
       UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
       picker.delegate = self;
       picker.sourcetype = UIImagePickerContrllerSourceTypeCamera;
       [self presentViewContrller:picker animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

I'm still a newbie in iOS development and is it possible to use a delegate?

Edit:CameraController doesn't have a nib.

Answer (score 2):

In `CameraController.h` add these lines:

```
@protocol CameraControllerDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)didFinishCapturingImage:(UIImage*)image;
@end
```

and add a property in `CameraController` class (in `CameraController.h`)

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) id<CameraControllerDelegate> delegate;
```

In `MainController.h`, add protocol in interface implementation; like this:

```
@interface MainController : NSObject <CameraControllerDelegate>
```

before you present/push `CameraController` from your `MainController.m` add this line:

```
cameraController.delegate = self;
```

In `MainController.m` implement `didFinishCapturingImage` method.

```
- (void)didFinishCapturingImage:(UIImage*)image {
    //your logic
}
```

in Image Picker Controller Delegate, add this line:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion: Nil];
    UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
    //this will send delegate callback to MainController
    [self.delegate didFinishCapturingImage:image];
}
```

**EDIT: Second Solution:**

Make a property in `CameraController.h` to keep instance of `MainController` object:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) MainController *mainController;
```

Assign self to `CameraController`'s instance's property `mainController` where you use `CameraController`:

```
cameraController.mainController = self;
```

Edit you `openCamera` method:

```
- (void) openCamera {
       UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
       picker.delegate = self.mainController; //important line
       picker.sourcetype = UIImagePickerContrllerSourceTypeCamera;
       [self.mainController presentViewContrller:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

and implement following method in `MainController.m`

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    //your logic
}
```

Don't forget to include `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` in `MainController.h`.

No need to create protocols and implement protocol methods..

Comment: Thanks for the answer but CameraController doesn't have a View how can I call CameraController to make it call UIImagePicker